# Ocultar item de menu overflow

Tags: java, android

Hice una clase java con una Toolbar y un menú desplegable para una aplicación Android con Android Studio.
De esa clase "Base.java" parto con todas mis Activitys para que hereden el menú y el comportamiento de los click. Quiero poder ocultar items de este menú según en que activity estoy o sea no se verán todos los de Base. Pruebo en la clase Base.java con setVisible(false) y funciona pero no se como llevar esto a mis Clases hijas.

```
public class Base extends AppCompatActivity   {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menugral, menu);
    **MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.item3);
    item.setVisible(false);   //oculta item3**
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // las aciones
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void action(int resid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, getText(resid) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Efectivamente oculta en este caso el item3.
Pero esto quiero hacer esto no en "Base.java" sino en las clases que heredan el comportamiento, por ejemplo:
`public class Principal extends Base  {
    private TextView titulo;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.principal);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarprin);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

}`

Si coloco las mismas líneas de código probadas en "Base.java" en tiempo de ejecución la app se cierra.
La siguiente etapa sería no solo poder ocultar algún item sino agregar alguno específico propio del activity o que venga de un fragmento.
Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré una forma de hacerlo aunque no se si es la adecuada:
Preparo mi menú general en la carpeta menu de Recursos con todos los items (xml) y orderInCategory="mi orden".
Creo una clase Base.java donde coloco el menú y su comportamiento:

```
public class Base extends AppCompatActivity   {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menugral, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // acciones
}}
```

Luego cada activity es una subclase de Base.java:

```
public class Principal extends Base  {
private TextView titulo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.principal);
    // asegurarse que aparesca la barra de acción en mi caso es una Toolbar

}
```

De esta forma por herencia muestra todo el menú de la super clase Base.java
Si quiero no mostrar algunos items del menú según en el activity que estoy hago lo siguiente en dicha Activity:

```
public class Buscar extends Base {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.buscar);
    // asegurarce de mostrar la Toolbar

}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menub) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menub);
    MenuItem item2 = menub.findItem(R.id.item2);
    item2.setVisible(false);   //hide item2
    return true;
}}
```

En el metodo onCreateOptionsMenu de la sub clase "Buscar" con super y MenuIten apunto a ; en este caso; "item2" del menu general y lo oculto.

No se si es lo adecuado pero me sirvió y mantengo el menú y su comportamiento en un solo lugar.